# Integrated webcam not working - Displayed as Unknown USB video device on Device Manager

Tags: windows-10, usb, skype, webcam

Anyone have any ideas on this issue?

My integrated webcam is displaying under "Unknown" as a USB device. It's not working on Skype or Zoom. Confirmed it's working on Windows 10 camera app. A few things I've tried:

- Update Windows
- Disable/Enable the device
- Reinstall Skype
- Checked Settings > Privacy > Camera allow apps to access camera ON

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The built-in camera should show in Camera in Device Manager. Are you sure that it's working with the Windows Camera app? Try re-installing the compatible driver.

Comment: Yes, it's working with the Windows Camera App. I can't seem to find the driver online. Searched for the hardware ID "USB\VID_1BCF&PID_28B8&REV_5413&MI_00" but no drivers around

Comment: Search Google for Dell, HP, or Lenovo Auto Detect driver Support utility and scan for the drivers.

Comment: yea, did that with Dell's SupportAssist program. Updated everything that was recommended but also no luck

Comment: Is it still showing an unknown device in Device Manager? Have you again checked with Zoom? and selected the Integrated Camera from the Zoom Video Icon?

Comment: Yup, it's still "Unknown - USB Video device" on Device manager. Tried on Zoom and Skype. Still blank while it works fine on Camera App.

Comment: The device is a Sunplus HD Webcam , WIndows has the drivers out of the box so it should not be "Unknown". Have you tried right clicking it, then installing the UVC driver manually for it?

Comment: @EugenRieck how/where do I find the correct driver for this Sunplus HD webcam?

Comment: You need the built-in UVC driver: Just chose it manually from the list.

Comment: Do I understand right that the camera is fully functional? Is the computer new? Have you tried to contact Dell Support?

Comment: @EugenRieck still the same - Got the message "Windows has successfully updated your drivers". But still displaying as unknown

Comment: @harrymc the camera is fully functional, but it's not a new laptop. Service plan expired in 2019

Comment: It may be an error in the firmware of the camera. But if the camera is fully functional, the fact that Device Manager doesn't correctly identify it is not a serious problem. Since the service plan has expired, there is not much that you can do, except perhaps search for a firmware update for the camera (if it exists).